# Android Studio - How to show the java byte code?

Tags: java, android, bytecode

Is there a way to see the Java byte code in Android Studio?

When I debug my program and step through it, Android Studio takes me to a file called "ActivityThread.java". 
I don't know what that is, it is over 5000 lines long so it can't be my byte code. 
I also get the message:
`source code does not match byte code`

Comment: what can you do if you see the byte code, why don't you share the code and the logcat

Comment: In fact, if you are viewing bytes code when debugging, you've put a foot inside the SDK. And we can assume that the hunted bug is not there ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityThread` is a class of the Android OS. It is quite natural, that you app executes native code, so don't be surprised.

The message `source code does not match byte code` hints to a mismatch of the platform libraries you have installed on the machine you use to compile and the ones of the device you run the app on. This is not unusual as there are several releases of these libraries even for the same target API. The best way to avoid it is to run the app in an emulator whose API matches your target API level defined by `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle`.

If I want to see the source for `ActivityThread`, I'd just add a variable to any class

```
ActivityThread a;
```

and use right-click "Go To -> Declaration and Usage" (Ctrl-B on my system) to jump to the source of it. There are probably other ways, but this is good enough for me.